# Override pytest ids for test case name

Tags: python, pytest

In my conftest.py file, I have:

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'item_id' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("item_id", item_id_data, ids=item_id_data)
```

I also have a test_item.py file, e.g.:

```
def test_item(item_id):
    assert True
```

How can I overwrite the value of 'ids' inside 'test_item' method (or inside test_item.py) to be something else? For example, when I want my tests to run, I want them to be: 
test['blah'] instead of test[item_id_data].